# Support gzip/zip file compression with a simple HTTP server in C

Tags: c, http, server, compression, gzip

I am writing a simple local HTTP server. When the browser visits the "localhost:port/path", the server side responses with corresponding local files to the browser.

The server would provide some additional functions like compressing the files before sending back to client via a socket. I am wondering how to compress a local file (eg. abc.jpg > abc.jpg.zip) by scripts. People suggested to use `<zlib.h>` or `<zip.h>` but I have no idea on how to use them for compression even I read the man page.

Could anyone give some hints for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the compression format you should use for HTTP response encoding is `gzip`or `zlib` format, which is `gzip` or `deflate` value in `Content-Encoding` header. The server should only encode it in a manner the browser accepts and can decode. Here are [more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) about compressing data on server.

`zlib.h` library can do the job of compression. There is a [detailed tutorail](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html) by its author. It is using `zlib` format in this example but using `gzip` isn't very different (call `deflateInit2()` instead of `deflateInit()`, reading the manual again will be inevitable).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot! Need some time to digest it.